# Installing Windows7 after Ubuntu 14.04, other recommendations not working

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I know this questions has been asked hundreds if not thousands of times, and I've actually successfully done this before, but I've tried several things on this system, and nothing has worked yet.  Here is my setup and the methods I've tried.

***Setup***

I have two SSD's in my laptop.

*/dev/sda* - This is my storage ssd (1tb)

*/dev/sdb* - This is my ssd used for ubuntu and windows (500gb)

|_    */dev/sdb1* - This is my ubuntu 14.04 install

|_*/dev/sdb2* - This is my Windows 7 install

I don't have a boot partition, it's on sdb1.

***Method1***

a. ) Resized my Ubuntu partition to make room for my windows 7 partition using gparted.  I created the partition as NTFS, and installed windows 7 correctly.  On reboot, the machine booted into windows 7 as expected.

b. ) I booted into an ubuntu live usb and used [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) instructions (the accepted answer).

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
sudo rm -rf /boot # Yes it was the live usb /boot, not the sdb1 /boot
sudo ln -s /mnt/boot /boot

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-pc
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
```

Upon reboot, I now see grub, but only ubuntu is listed.

**Method2**

a.) I completely redid the windows 7 install, since I kind of regretted how small I made the partition.  I then booted into windows 7 successfully.

b.) While in windows 7, I downloaded and installed EasyBCD, and tried to let it make the changes (I've done this before and it worked, but I really didn't want to do this again since I would much rather use grub).

After this method, when I reboot I got nothing but a 0 on the screen.  Obviously something went wrong.

**Method3**

a.) I reinstalled windows 7 yet again, and decided to let a Linux utility try and solve my problem.  I used boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

I then ran the recommended repair, and after reboot I got the exact same result as Method1.  The reboot showed grub, but only ubuntu was listed.

**Method4**

a.)  I assumed I made a mistake on one of the steps, and I went back and retraced my steps 3 times each.  That sounds ridiculous, but I really didn't want to post a question on something so simple.

b.)  I posted this ridiculous question on askubuntu.com.  Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT1**

Along with Method1 and Method3, when trying to reinstall grub, I also tried [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) recommended method.  I had the same thing happen, Grub works, but nothing shows but ubuntu.

Comment: Since the automatic ways aren't working, I tried googling for "manually add windows to grub" and found this:http://technologytales.com/2010/11/21/manually-adding-an-entry-for-windows-7-to-an-ubuntu-grub2-menu/  Sadly I don't have personal experience with this solution though, just thought it might help.  (it's also kind of old)

Comment: Thanks, that did help me understand how grub works a little better, but for some reason after I added an entry in 40_custom, and updated grub, the entry wasn't actually added into /boot/grub/grub.cfg.  I'm looking into that now.

Comment: I definitely just had a typo on that last try.  It worked adding the custom grub entry.  Thanks!  I still am super curious about why the normal method doesn't work for some systems.

Comment: How about I post it as an answer then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the automatic ways aren't working, I tried googling for "manually add windows to grub" and found [this](http://technologytales.com/2010/11/21/manually-adding-an-entry-for-windows-7-to-an-ubuntu-grub2-menu/).

The linked answer suggests the following:

> The first step is to edit /etc/grub.d/40_custom (using SUDO) and add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
menuentry ‘Windows 7′ {
set root='(hd0,msdos2)’
chainloader +1 }
```

Then running

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Sadly I don't have personal experience with this solution though, just thought it might help. (it's also kind of old)

Comment: Good show! I can confirm that I have used this method more than once in the past with success. I, too, have no idea why the OP encountered problems, but I have encountered them as well. Not all systems boot or work the same, I suppose.

Comment: this worked for me on Windows 10 except I needed to use `(hd0,msdos1)` with  my installation

Comment: Good job modifying the answer to fit your situation!