# Windows 10 Technical Preview not in GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, bios

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 a while ago. Then I followed guides like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) on how to install windows after Ubuntu and I installed Windows 10 Technical Preview after Ubuntu. Then I booted up from a live CD, installed boot-repair, then I did a recommended repair. It put GRUB back there, but Windows 10 isn't on the GRUB menu. `os-prober` doesn't detect it, and it doesn't show up in the output if I do `update-grub`.

I've done boot-repair again, but nothing happened and I don't know what to do.

I have a BIOS motherboard and I have an MBR, with 4 primary partitions.

Comment: It's quite possible Grub can't yet ID Windows 10.  My guess, also, is 15.10 Grub will have support, but not all Ubuntu versions will

Comment: If that's so, and it sounds pretty likely, can I manually add the OS to grub or something?

Comment: This answer addresses adding windows manually.  I don't know if it applies to Win 10 but you can take a look. http://askubuntu.com/questions/600042/installing-windows7-after-ubuntu-14-04-other-recommendations-not-working/600063#600063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Organic Marble and Thomas W. for helping me solve this. Apparently Grub doesn't support the Windows 10 Technical Preview so you have to add the grub menu entry manually.

1. Open `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` as root with gedit or another text editor.
2. Then you have to add an entry at the end of the file. Mine looked like this.

   `'Windows 10 Technical Preview' {
   set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
   chainloader +1
   }`

The name doesn't matter, and the `set root='(hd0,msdos2)'` command will vary. `hd0` means my first hard drive, and `msdos2` tells what partition the OS is on.

1. run `sudo update-grub`
2. To check, open up `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and check if there's a new entry.

Comment: Please consider marking your answer [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I thoroughly disagree. I recently installed **Windows 10 Pro Technical Preview**, *build 10158*, and went on to reinstall GRUB, and it works fine. I am dual booting Arch Linux and Windows 10. `os-prober` certainly detects Windows.

Though I am not sure if these are necessary, but mount you Windows 10 partition (`/dev/sdxZ`) before `os-prober`.

Install [Grub Customizer](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/) and try that. It should find Windows 10 for you. Otherwise, At the very least, you won't have to write GRUB configuration every time you need to update.

Comment: I guess your case is different than mine. I did mount my windows 10 partition before using `os-prober`. Also, to clarify, are you disagreeing with my answer, my question, or one of my comments?

Comment: os-prober worked for me. You mentioned that GRUB doesn't work with Windows 10. I was disagreeing with that.

Comment: Arch Linux is known to update packages earlier than Ubuntu does. So you might be simply using a newer version of `os-prober`.