# Grub not showing Windows 10 after ubuntu using boot-repair to repair grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, boot-repair, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit installed I installed Windows 10, i used `boot-repair` to fix the grub but now, when grub comes up, windows is not listed, and after `grub-update` the problem remains, and the windows partition is still untouched as I have checked using `gparted`.

Comment: You can try adding it manually like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/600042/installing-windows7-after-ubuntu-14-04-other-recommendations-not-working/600063#600063